# PHP Simple HTML DOM and Dropdown Element Selected Option

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, dom

I'm generating dropdown inputs with php simple html dom. I have some values from database and according them i will add 'selected' value into my select->option dom elements.

```
<select name="myDropDown" id="someID">
   <option value="someValue1">Value1Value</option>
   <option value="someValue2">Value2Value</option>
   <option value="someValue3">Value3Value</option>
</select>
```

this is the default one. i would like to add value like this, check on option 2 :

```
<select name="myDropDown" id="someID">
   <option value="someValue1">Value1Value</option>
   <option value="someValue2" selected>Value2Value</option>
   <option value="someValue3">Value3Value</option>
</select>
```

and while doing that i want to use my plugin.

```
<?php    
    $html = new simple_html_dom();
    $html->load('
           <select name="myDropDown" id="someID">
             <option value="someValue1">Value1Value</option>
             <option value="someValue2">Value2Value</option>
             <option value="someValue3">Value3Value</option>
           </select>
          ');
    echo $html;
?>
```

Everything works nicely until here. Yeah now i need to insert **selected** into my second option. I don't know how to do this with PHP Simple HTML DOM, or i'm missing something in the documentation : http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_access

What i have tried so far and got many errors in my **php** section :

```
<?php
$html = new simple_html_dom();
   $html->load('
              <select name="myDropDown" id="someID">
                 <option value="someValue1">Value1Value</option>
                 <option value="someValue2">Value2Value</option>
                 <option value="someValue3">Value3Value</option>
              </select>
              ');
   //here's where i'm trying to reach the child nodes :    
   $ret = $html->getElementById('someID');
   $ret->children(2)->GOTTADOSOMETHINGHEREANDIREALLYDUNNO;
   echo $html;
?>
```

By the way, if you offer another easy way to do this, i'd appreciate.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Can't understand the need to use `simple_html_dom` here

Comment: Check out here : http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_access first i need to create instance of this plugin, then i'm generating dom with it. Why am i using it : because i don't want to mess with javascript in this section of my project.

Comment: Yeah but is it really required for you to use `simple_html_dom`? You can do this without it

Comment: @GonsaloSousa yes i can do that with javascript, or they will be fixed, i need to change the selected value according the values i got from db.

Comment: Maybe you are complicating the problem, `$db_value = SOMETHING; echo '<option value="someValue2" '.(($db_value==SOMETHING)?' selected':'').'>Value2Value</option>';`. This may help you achieve the results without using `simple_html_dom `.

Comment: @GonsaloSouse yeah, i need to try that one too, thanks !

Comment: This guy is clearly quite new to website development, and while telling him he is going a little overkill is certainly the right thing to do, helping him is also the right thing to do. He's learning here, and while what he's working on may be somewhat important, he's not creating the next Facebook or a high traffic website (I would expect) where performance is crucial.

Comment: I'd also like to add that others come looking for the same answer who may need PHP Simple HTML DOM a little more.

Comment: @iWontStop all of you are doing a great job. I'm not a newbie (but also still learning as you say) and i like making things complicated sometimes. I'm creating a big project and using other functionalities of simple dom, so i wanted to start here. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With minimal research you can figure this out for yourself.

`$ret->children(2)->selected = true;`

Comment: that's the answer i wanted. Tried this one too, but did something wrong with children indexing. Easy answer, easy solution, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Why you use simple_html_dom and not simply a template file (with PHP)?

```
<select name="test" <?php if($selected){echo 'selected'}?> />
```

Or even better Smarty.

```
<select name="test" {if $selected}selected{/if} />
```

Simple_html_dom is a class for parsing complex html documents like exchanging image urls or something like that. I cant' see any reason why you need to use this class.

Comment: I'm using it another part of my projects, and want to learn, but thank you !

Comment: `§` - What use is this symbol?

Answer (score 1):

for getting Dropdown Element Selected Option with Simple HTML DOM
just try this simple and easy method

```
 $element =  $html->find('#selectIDGoesHere',0)->find('option');     
        foreach($element as $elemen) {         
            echo "Display text:".($elemen->plaintext)."<br>"; 
            echo "value:".($elemen->value)."<br>";
        }
```